# How does listview differ from listactivity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I would like to know what is the diff b/w listview and listactivity. According to my understanding, if we have only list in a screen then better to use listactivity correct?.
If we want to add either simple button at the bottom of list or include search on top of list, then we should use listview in layout file right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List activity is the activity which has a listview as its layout by default... and you can even customise the listview in the ListActivity by using a layout inflater and adding views...and yes.. for simple listview use list activity.. and to add such components use listview in layout.
[To customise your rows in the list use listactivity like this..](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071253/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/08/custom-view-in-your-listactivity-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i want to add some buttons at the bottom of list or to include search on the header then we should use listview in layout xml right?